# get and search elasticsearch data with python rest api

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I am having an issue getting and searching data through the api. I need to filter data by status is updated at a particular date

```
import json
import requests

    res = requests.get('http://100.97.62.106:9200/swbsrepo/swb/_search)
    def search(uri,date):
        query =json.dumps({
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":[
                    {"match": {"Status": "Updated"}},
                    {"match":{"timestamp": date}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        })
    print(query)
    response = requests.get(uri,query)
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    print(results)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uri = ('http://100.97.62.106:9200/swbsrepo/_swb/_search')
    uri = ('http://elasticsearchip:port/index/type/_search')
    search(uri, "2019-10-29")
```

but I am getting error please help me

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you please post the error (seems kind of logical to me).
 
2) Your example would benefit a bit from a cleanup (usage of ES-host is rather confusing)
3) I'm already inclined to promote following Python syntax with regards to a date. Not saying this is the cause of your error but this makes your date a real date.

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 29)
```